# PHP query Access database on Intranet

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, intranet

I know there are other questions about how to query a MS Access database using PHP, but my situation is a little different:

Currently my company is using a program a former employee developed in MS Access. The program is severely outdated and the VBA inside is just a mess its not worth fixing. He used two ODBC connections to connect to and query SQL databases that are controlled by corporate (ie - we have no admin access to this). I thought it would be interesting to develop a PHP driven program that will replicate the old program, but with some additional features we all desired.

The issue here is that even though its highly inefficient, I will likely need to query an MS Access database program (which queries corporate SQL files) located on our intranet and I don't know if PHP can query a private intranet.

Is it possible to develop a PHP application that is hosted on a server, yet queries an Access database located on out private intranet?

Or, is it possible to host the PHP application on our intranet - that way it would be easy to query the Access database?

If either, could you provide some advice on how I could achieve this?

Comment: This link might be worth looking http://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/. Give it a try cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use db odbc >> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp

Also Try using PDO

```
<?php
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\accounts.mdb;Uid=Admin");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } 
?>
```

Comment: So I would have to locate the PHP program on our intranet?

Comment: you need to have the database readable and writable by the php script,
Yo will also need to install a local web server like Xampp and then point an Ip adress to the http://localhost of the point the comp having the local server.